# Error Appending to IsolatedStorageFile

Tags: windows-phone-7, append, isolatedstorage

I am having some problems with Isolated file store , I am trying to append to a file, but when I use the code below, I get an error about invalid Arguments on this line

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream("Folder\\barcodeinfo.txt", FileMode.Append, 
                                     FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myStore))
```

I think it has something to do with the Filemode.Append.. I am trying to append to the file rather than create new

```
// Obtain the virtual store for the application.
IsolatedStorageFile myStore = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
// Create a new folder and call it "MyFolder".
myStore.CreateDirectory("Folder");

// Specify the file path and options.
using (var isoFileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Folder\\barcodeinfo.txt", FileMode.Append, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, myStore))
{
      //Write the data
      using (var isoFileWriter = new StreamWriter(isoFileStream))
      {
            isoFileWriter.WriteLine(textBox1.Text);
            isoFileWriter.WriteLine(textBox2.Text);
            isoFileWriter.WriteLine(textBox3.Text);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no overload that takes two [FileModes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefilestream.aspx). It should be

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream("Folder\\barcodeinfo.txt", FileMode.Append, 
                                     FileAccess.Write, myStore));
```

Important thing to note about [FileMode.Append](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is:

> [FileMode.Append] Opens the file if it exists and seeks to the end of the file, or
>   creates a new file. Append can only be used in conjunction with Write.
>   Attempting to seek to a position before the end of the file will throw
>   an IOException and any attempt to read fails and throws an
>   NotSupportedException.

which is why [FileAccess.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) is used.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have `FileMode.Append, FileMode.OpenOrCreate`.  That is 2 file modes.  The first parameter is be `FileMode` and the second should be `FileAccess`.

That should fix your problem.